# swagger ajax preflight options

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, swagger, preflight

The code below is what I am running.  Go easy on me for code style... I am new :p

I am simply trying to make an Ajax GET request from an HTML page on one server to my API on a second server.  I have already climbed the CORS mountain and won (meaning I was originally getting CORS errors but have solved that issue).  Now I am getting the exception below.  So here is the big question:

What is the correct way to define a global OPTIONS handler using Swagger to properly respond to the Ajax Preflight request?

Alternatively if I am being a total Noob... please educate me on what I am doing wrong.  I really do appreciate the support here... this one has got me stumped.

To cutoff the "You should run your HTML and Node on the same server." response... In order to properly scale and secure you should be running your API separately from your frontend.  In my case the frontend will be a full scale web application and the API used to separate visual creativity from engineering brilliance.  :)

Here is the scenario...

Client:  ANY
Web Server:  Apache on Amazon Linux AMI using jQuery 1.6.2
Content:  Simple html page with form using ajax to make a GET, or POST, call to my API
API Server:  Amazon Linux AMI running Node Swagger Express (updated to current)
Behavior:
Browse to HTML page
Click Submit Button
Exception is printed to console

Exception:

```
Error: Path [/ping] defined in Swagger, but OPTIONS operation is not.
    at middleware (/var/node/api/node_modules/swagger-express-mw/node_modules/swagger-node-runner/lib/connect_middleware.js:31:21)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /var/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (/var/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
    at next (/var/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
    at /var/node/api/app.js:38:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (/var/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:302:13)
    at /var/node/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:270:7
```

Result (as returned by Postman):

```
{
  "result": "pong"
}
```

Headers (as returned by Postman):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials → true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → X-Requested-With,content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Length → 17
Content-Type → application/json; charset=utf-8
Date → Tue, 01 Dec 2015 08:09:03 GMT
ETag → W/"11-df5e0e4c"
X-Powered-By → Express
```

Note:  No response is returned by API due to exception.

Web Page Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="author" content="Rusty Chapin">
    <meta name="description" content="Sample execution of API to create new contact">
    <title>Create New Contact</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           var getResults = function(){
                var contactemail = $('#contactemail').val();
                var contactname = $('#contactname').val();

                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url: "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10010/contact",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    data: { contactemail: contactemail, contactname: contactname },
                    success: function(response){
                        $('#results').html('<h2 class="loading">Contact ID: ' + 
                                response[0].contactid + '<br>Contact Email: ' + 
                                response[0].contactemail + '<br>Contact Name: ' + 
                                response[0].contactname + '<h2 />');
                    },
                    error: function(response){
                        $('#results').html('<h2 class="loading">Response: ' + 
                                response + '<h2 />');
                    }
                });
           };


           $('#submit').click(getResults);
        });

   </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <h1>Create New Contact</h1>
    </header>
    <form>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="contactemail" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="contactname" />
        <button id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <section id="results">
        <br>
    </section>
    <footer>
       Created for use with...
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

API Code:
app.js

```
'use strict';


var SwaggerExpress = require('swagger-express-mw');
var SwaggerUi = require('swagger-tools/middleware/swagger-ui');
var app = require('express')();
module.exports = app; // for testing


var config = {
  appRoot: __dirname // required config
};


SwaggerExpress.create(config, function(err, swaggerExpress) {
    if (err) { throw err; }


    // Add swagger-ui (This must be before swaggerExpress.register)
    app.use(SwaggerUi(swaggerExpress.runner.swagger));

    // Add headers
    app.use(function (req, res, next) {


       // Website you wish to allow to connect
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');


       // Request methods you wish to allow
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');


       // Request headers you wish to allow
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');


       // Website you wish to allow to connect
       res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');


       // Pass to next layer of middleware
       next();
    });


    // install middleware
    swaggerExpress.register(app);


    var port = process.env.PORT || 10010;


    app.listen(port);


    if (swaggerExpress.runner.swagger.paths['/ping']) {
      console.log('running at: http://127.0.0.1:' + port);
      console.log('Ping test: http://127.0.0.1:' + port + '/ping');
    }
});
```

ping.js

```
'use strict';


var util = require('util');


module.exports = {
  ping: ping
};


function ping(req, res) {
  // this sends back a JSON response which is a single string
  return res.json({ result: 'pong' });
}
```

swagger.yaml

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  version: "0.0.1"
  title: My API
# during dev, should point to your local machine
host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:10010
# basePath prefixes all resource paths 
basePath: /
# 
schemes:
  # tip: remove http to make production-grade
  - http
  - https
# format of bodies a client can send (Content-Type)
consumes:
  - application/json
# format of the responses to the client (Accepts)
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /contact:
    x-swagger-router-controller: contact
    post:
      description: Creates a new contact
      operationId: create
      parameters:
        - name: contactemail
          in: query
          description: Email address of new contact
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: contactname
          in: query
          description: Name of new contact
          required: false
          type: string
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/CreateContactSuccess"
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
  /ping:
    # binds a127 app logic to a route
    x-swagger-router-controller: ping
    get:
      description: Returns 'pong' to the caller
      # used as the method name of the controller
      operationId: ping
      responses:
        "200":
          description: Success
          schema:
            # a pointer to a definition
            $ref: "#/definitions/PingResponse"
        # responses may fall through to errors
        default:
          description: Error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/ErrorResponse"
  /swagger:
    x-swagger-pipe: swagger_raw
# complex objects have schema definitions
definitions:
  CreateContactSuccess:
    required:
      - contactid
      - contactemail
      - contactname
    properties:
      contactid:
        type: string
      contactemail:
        type: string
      contactname:
        type: string
  PingResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
  ErrorResponse:
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
```

default.yaml

```
# swagger configuration file

# values in the swagger hash are system configuration for swagger-node
swagger:

  fittingsDirs: [ api/fittings ]
  defaultPipe: null
  swaggerControllerPipe: swagger_controllers  # defines the standard processing pipe for controllers

  # values defined in the bagpipes key are the bagpipes pipes and fittings definitions
  # (see https://github.com/apigee-127/bagpipes)
  bagpipes:

    _router:
      name: swagger_router
      mockMode: false
      mockControllersDirs: [ api/mocks ]
      controllersDirs: [ api/controllers ]

    _swagger_validate:
      name: swagger_validator
      validateResponse: true

    # pipe for all swagger-node controllers
    swagger_controllers:
      - onError: json_error_handler
      - cors
      - swagger_security
      - _swagger_validate
      - express_compatibility
      - _router

    # pipe to serve swagger (endpoint is in swagger.yaml)
    swagger_raw:
      name: swagger_raw

# any other values in this file are just loaded into the config for application access...
```

Comment: Add OPTIONS path in your api.yml file

Comment: Could you give a sample of what the options path should look like? I have tried adding an options path in but don't believe I have the correct configuration. Is there a way to add a global options handler or do I need to add it to every endpoint?

Comment: Under `/ping:` add a `post:` section. Look at Swaggers page for exact config.